# Hi, how spring-kafka handle consumer thread?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

can someone please tell me does spring-Kafka has a feature like spring-JMS which can dynamically spin up threads or reduce threads based on load?

By use Kafka, do we need to worry about this thread management stuff? I know that the best practice for Kafka consumer is to have an equal amount of threads as how many partitions you have on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring for Apache Kafka does not dynamically adjust the number of consumer threads in any way. The partitions will be distributed across the number of threads you configure.

You could query the topic and configure the container appropriately before starting it.

Comment: You could query the topic and configure the container appropriately before starting it.